# Angular/Jest - Test that the subject has thrown error after setter is called

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a class that is responsible for setting the theme for my application.

I'm trying to test that it throws an error if you give it a theme that it does not recognise. The code is shown below -

```js
@Injectable()
export class ThemeSwitcherService {
    public static THEME_NAME_COOKIE = 'THEME_NAME';

    private readonly _themeNameBehaviourSubject$: BehaviorSubject<string>;
    private readonly _document: Document;
    private readonly _themes: Map<string, Map<string, string>>;

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document, themeConfig: ApplicationThemeConfig) {
        this._themeNameBehaviourSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
        this._document = document;
        this._themes = themeConfig.moduleThemes;

        this.initialise();
    }

    public get currentThemeNameSubscription(): Observable<string> {
        return this._themeNameBehaviourSubject$.asObservable();
    }

    public set themeName(themeName: string) {
        this._themeNameBehaviourSubject$.next(themeName);
    }

    private setTheme(themeName: string): void {
        const selectedTheme: Map<string, string> | undefined = this._themes.get(themeName);

        if (typeof selectedTheme === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error(`Could not find theme named ${ themeName }. Please add ${ themeName } to your forRoot configuration`);
        }

        selectedTheme.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
            const root = this._document.body;
            root.style.setProperty(key, value);
        });
    }

    private initialise(): void {
        const storedTheme = Cookies.get(ThemeSwitcherService.THEME_NAME_COOKIE);

        if (storedTheme) {
            this.themeName = storedTheme;
        }

        if (!storedTheme) {
            const firstThemeAvailable = this._themes.entries().next().value;
            this.themeName = firstThemeAvailable[0];
        }

        this.subscribeToThemeNameSubject();
    }

    private subscribeToThemeNameSubject(): void {
        this._themeNameBehaviourSubject$
            .pipe(tap((themeName: string) => Cookies.set(ThemeSwitcherService.THEME_NAME_COOKIE, themeName)))
            .subscribe({
                next: (themeName: string) => this.setTheme(themeName),
                error: (error) => console.error(error)
            });
    }
}
```

when the `themeName` setter is called with a value, it updates a behaviour subject and calls the private `setTheme(themeName: string)` method, this throws an error if the theme is unknown.

I'm trying to test this line of code:

```js
if (typeof selectedTheme === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error(`Could not find theme named ${ themeName }. Please add ${ themeName } to your forRoot configuration`);
        }
```

I have this so far:

```js
import { ThemeSwitcherService } from './theme-switcher.service';
import { ApplicationThemeConfig } from '../setup/application-theme.config';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ApplicationThemeConfigurationFactory } from '../../../config/theme/factories/application-theme-configuration.factory';
import { ThemeModule } from '../theme.module';
import DoneCallback = jest.DoneCallback;

describe('ThemeSwitcherService', () => {
    let subject: ThemeSwitcherService;

    describe('Given a theme that does not exist', () => {

        beforeEach(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [ThemeModule],
                providers: [
                    {
                        provide: ApplicationThemeConfig,
                        useValue: {
                            moduleThemes: ApplicationThemeConfigurationFactory.getThemes()
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            subject = TestBed.inject<ThemeSwitcherService>(ThemeSwitcherService);
        });

        describe('When the theme is selected', () => {
            it('Then an error is thrown', (done: DoneCallback) => {
                subject.themeName = 'Something';
                subject.currentThemeNameSubscription
                    .subscribe((currentTheme) => {
                        expect(currentTheme).toThrowError();
                        done();
                    });

            });
        });
    });
});
```

But I keep getting the error:

`Error: Could not find theme named Something. Please add Something to your forRoot configuration`

Which is what I'd expect but I'd also expect my unit test to pass. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Drenai said, there was no need for the `BehaviourSubject`. I've removed the behaviour subject and the service has become clean and should be easy to test.

Refactor:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ThemeSwitcherService {
    public static THEME_NAME_COOKIE = 'THEME_NAME';

    private _currentThemeName: string;
    private readonly _document: Document;
    private readonly _themes: Map<string, Map<string, string>>;

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document, themeConfig: ApplicationThemeConfig) {
        this._document = document;
        this._themes = themeConfig.moduleThemes;

        this.initialise();
    }

    public get currentThemeName(): string {
        return this._currentThemeName;
    }

    public setTheme(themeName: string): void {
        const selectedTheme: Map<string, string> | undefined = this._themes.get(themeName);

        if (typeof selectedTheme === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error(`Could not find theme named ${ themeName }. Please add ${ themeName } to your forRoot configuration`);
        }

        selectedTheme.forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
            const root = this._document.body;
            root.style.setProperty(key, value);
        });

        this._currentThemeName = themeName;
        Cookies.set(ThemeSwitcherService.THEME_NAME_COOKIE, themeName);
    }

    private initialise(): void {
        const storedTheme = Cookies.get(ThemeSwitcherService.THEME_NAME_COOKIE);

        if (storedTheme) {
            this._currentThemeName = storedTheme;
        }

        if (!storedTheme) {
            const firstThemeAvailable = this._themes.entries().next().value;
            this._currentThemeName = firstThemeAvailable[0];
        }

        this.setTheme(this._currentThemeName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `throw new Error` isn't part of an observale flow so it won't be captured by the subscription to  `currentThemeNameSubscription`

Quickest option is wrapping the call to
`this.setTheme(themeName)` in a regular `try/catch` block and call an error handling method (spy on the error handling method in your test)

I'm not sure of the purpose of the `BehaviorSubject` in this case tbh

Comment: Yeah, I completely stripped out the behaviour subject and it's become so clean and simple. I'll add the new version now as an answer.